# Can't enable addons in IE10 from a guest account

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I can't use the Flash player or anything else in IE10 from a guest account on Windows 8, because the enable/disable buttons in the 'manage addons' are greyed out. I'm not using the Metro version of the browser, just the regular IE in desktop mode. Everything (obviously) works fine in my regular admin privileged account.

Using that is not an option, since I want a functioning guest account for when visiting family wants to use my computer. Is there a fix?

Comment: What exact version of Flash Player are you attempting to use?  What have you tried already?  Have you tried removing and re-installing Flash Player?

Comment: If I login with my normal account and check the flash version on Adobe's site, it is the latest for Windows 8 and works correctly.

Comment: _Have you tried re-installing Flash Player?_